# Move elements from one List to another with Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm playing with Immutable.js. I came across this problem and I wasn't able to find a nice solution: I have two lists, A and B, and I want to filter out some elements from the list A using a custom `predicate` function and add them to the list B. Both are immutable.

The obvious problem here is that the return value of `A.filter(predicate)` is a new updated instance and the removed elements are lost. I could first add those filtered elements:

```
B = B.concat(A.filterNot(predicate));
A = A.filter(predicate);
```

That would mean cycling over the original list twice. The only way around this is to add a side effect to the filtering function:

```
let tmp = [];
B = B.filter(el => { 
    if (!predicate(el)) {
        tmp.push(el);
        return false;
    } else return true;
});
A = A.concat(tmp);
```

That however looks a bit hacky. I don't think the `filter` method is supposed to be used this way. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not just iterate over A splitting it into two temporary arrays? So basically, an `.each` iteration on A?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming here B is the array you want to filter, and A gets the filtered elements concatenated to it: (like your second code example), I think this is the best you can do.

```
A.withMutations( (list) => {
  B = B.filter( 
    (el) => { 
      if (!predicate(el)) {
          list.push(el);
          return false;
      } else return true;
    }
  );
  return list;
});
```

or, arguably more readable:

```
A.withMutations( (list) => {
  B = B.filter( (el) => { return (!predicate(el)) ? !!list.push(el) : true; 
      });
  return list;
});
```

If you find yourself moving items from one list to another often, it is probably best to write a method, `transferTo` that does the above.

From [`withMutations`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/withMutations):

> Note: Not all methods can be used on a mutable collection or within
>   withMutations! Only set, push, pop, shift, unshift and merge may be
>   used mutatively.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely looks better, although the core idea is the same.